# Specify from what index to start looping in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

The content if pulled from a while loop that I used to fetch a query. I need to sort the content from different starting point of the array, let's say results from indexes 5to 8 and ignore 0 to 4 or 9 to 12.

```
<?php
$i='0';
foreach($articulos as $articdos){
?>
<div class="cajon4centro">
<div class="">
  <a href="efecto.php?libelula=noticias&artic=<?= $articdos['id']; ?>&gen=<?= $articdos['genero']; ?>&id=<?= $articdos['id'] ?>">
    <div class="c4img">
    <img src="img/chica/<?= $articdos['foto']; ?>" alt="" />
    <div class="titC4">
      <?= $articdos['titulo']; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<?php
if ($i++ == 3) break;
} ?>
```

As it is right now it all starts from index 0 and I want it to start after the 6th index... Can this be done?

Comment: In a foreach loop, it's got to start at the beginning since it's not using specific indexes.  The only way around that would be to use a different query to get only the results you actually want to loop through.  However, by using a counter, you could check your counter and only perform actions once your counter is from 5-8 or whatever you want.  The foreach loop would still loop through all results, but would only perform specified actions on the counted iterations you wanted it to.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to use more than one query to minimize db connections.  I know I can put in practice your suggestion for the while loop but I would have to generate more than one query, Am I on the wrong track?

Comment: There's more than one way to accomplish this, but you could keep your single query and just use the counter like I said above.  Having the foreach loop run through iterations in which it does nothing while waiting for the counter to indicate the iteration you want will take very little time while doing exactly what you want to do here.

Comment: Is it better to use a for loop then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do this using a counter:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($articulos as $articdos){
        if ($i >= 5 && $i <= 8) {
?>
    //Your HTML code here
<?php
        } // end if block
        $++i;
    } // end foreach loop
?>
```

During the loops where the if statement is false, no HTML code will be executed or output, and unless you're looping through thousands of records, the time taken during those loops where nothing is done will be negligible.

Instead of testing for a number, you could also test the data inside `$articdos` if you were only looking for specific records with specific data in them.

Comment: I see, instead of using break to end the loop you specified the start and end on an if. Love it.
Thank you Sgt AJ.